# Why is my lightning js function freezing at the event.setparams?

Tags: javascript, lightning-aura-components

I am trying to get this demo working in my org: http://www.johnbrunswick.com/2015/01/salesforce-lightning-example-ideas-experiment/

My component has an onclick that is supposed to display a modal card. When the onclick goes to the javascript it appears to be hanging up on the lightning event setparams. I've added a window.alert before and after the setparams and I only get the screen pop before.

Here is the component. The line that I'm having trouble with is:

> div class="card box-shadow-outset" onclick="{!c.openIdeaDetail}"
>   data-ideaid="{!p.Id}"

```
<aura:component controller="Merchants.CaseCards" implements="force:appHostable">
<aura:attribute name="idea" type="Idea" default="{'sobjectType': 'Idea'}"/>
<aura:attribute name="ideas" type="Idea[]"/>
<aura:attribute name="profilePhotoUrl" type="String"/>
<aura:attribute name="ideaComments" type="IdeaComment[]"/>
<aura:attribute name="textareaNewIdeaValue" type="String" default="" />
<aura:attribute name="searchTerm" type="String" default="" />


<aura:attribute name="newIdea" type="Idea"
                default="{ 'sobjectType': 'Idea',
                         'Title': '',
                         'Body': '',
                         'CommunityId': '09ao0000000a8tqAAA'
                         }"/> 
<aura:attribute name="newIdeaComment" type="IdeaComment" default="{ 'sobjectType': 'IdeaComment', 'CommentBody': ''}"/>         



<Merchants:load filesInParallel="/resource/bootstrapcssmin.sfcss,/resource/animate.sfcss,/resource/bootstrapswitchcss.sfcss"
          filesInSeries="/resource/isotope.sfjs,/resource/jquerymin.sfjs,/resource/modernizr.sfjs,/resource/timeago.sfjs,/resource/bootstrapjs.sfjs,/resource/bootstrapswitch.sfjs" />

<aura:handler event="Merchants:staticResourcesLoaded" action="{!c.initScripts}"/>    
<!-- This attribute will hold out JS object that represents our "cards" -->    
<aura:attribute name="objIsotope" type="Object" />

<!-- Note - fixed header will only work in non S1 environments with our example -->
<div id="fixedheader">
    <div class="titleheader">
        <img src="/resource/BulletTrainLogo" class="logo"/>
    </div>


    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">

            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapsible">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
            </div>

            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse tabs" id="navbar-collapsible">

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="tabitem active">
                        <a id="buttonFilterFresh" href="#" onclick="{!c.getFilterFresh}" class="filterbutton">fresh<span></span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="tabitem">
                        <a id="buttonFilterOpen" href="#" onclick="{!c.getFilterTop}" class="filterbutton">trending<span></span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="tabitem">
                        <a id="buttonFilterComments" href="#" onclick="{!c.getFilterComments}" class="filterbutton">comments<span></span></a>
                    </li> 
                    <li class="tabitem">
                        <a id="buttonFilterTotal" href="#" onclick="{!c.getFilterVoteTotal}" class="filterbutton">total votes<span></span></a>
                    </li>          
                </ul>

            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>               

</div>       


<!-- Using Isotope library - if used commercially you will need a license.  Very inexpensive and worth it! -->    
<div id="grid-gallery" class="grid-gallery" style="-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;">
    <section class="grid-wrap">
        <div class="grid"> 

            <aura:iteration items="{!v.ideas}" var="p">
                <div class="card box-shadow-outset" onclick="{!c.openIdeaDetail}" data-ideaid="{!p.Id}">

                    <div class="carddetails">
                        <img src="{!p.Merchants__PhotoURL__c}" class="profilephoto"/>

                        <aura:if isTrue="{!p.NumComments > 0}">
                            <div class="commentcount">                           
                                {!p.NumComments}
                            </div>
                        </aura:if>                                    

                        <h3>{!p.Title}</h3>
                        <p>
                            by {!p.Merchants__Submitted_By__c} <span class="timeago case-date" title="{!p.CreatedDate}">{!p.CreatedDate}</span> 
                        </p>
                    </div>

                    <!-- The "chart" is the color that is applied to each card background -->
                    <Merchants:VoteChart ideaObject="{!p}"/>

                    <!-- Hidden to be used for filtering - could be more elegant, but this is simple -->
                    <p class="votescore" style="display:none">{!p.VoteScore}</p>
                    <p class="numcomments" style="display:none">{!p.NumComments}</p>
                    <p class="freshdate" style="display:none">{!p.CreatedDate}</p>
                    <p class="votetotal" style="display:none">{!p.VoteTotal}</p>
                </div>
            </aura:iteration>

        </div>
    </section>
</div>

<!-- Bootstrap modal used to show details for a given idea -->
<div class="modal fade" id="ideadetail">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header detail">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">{!v.Idea.title}</h4>
                <Merchants:renderHTML rawHTML="{!v.idea.Body}"/>
                <Merchants:VoteBox parentIdeaId="{!v.idea.id}"/>  

            </div>
            <div class="modal-body comments">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <aura:iteration items="{!v.ideaComments}" var="ic" indexVar="i">
                        <div class="row comment fade-in" style="{!'-webkit-animation-delay:' + i + '00ms;'}">
                            <div class="col-md-1"><img src="{!ic.CreatorSmallPhotoUrl}" class="commentphoto"/></div>
                            <div class="col-md-11"><div class="ideacommentbody">{!ic.CommentBody}<br/>
                                <span class="timeago case-date" title="{!ic.CreatedDate}">{!ic.CreatedDate}</span></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </aura:iteration>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">

                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="row commentcreate">
                        <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-1"><img src="{!v.profilePhotoUrl}" class="commentphoto currentuser"/></div>
                        <div class="col-xs-9 col-md-10">

                            <div class="group">
                                <ui:inputText aura:id="commentBody" label="" value="{!v.newIdeaComment.CommentBody}" required="true"/>
                                <span class="highlight"></span>
                                <span class="bar"></span>
                                <label class="material">Your Comment</label>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-1">
                            <a href="#" onclick="{!c.postIdeaComment}" data-ideaid="{!v.idea.id}" class="linkstandard">Post</a>
                            <!--<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="{!c.postIdeaComment}" data-ideaid="{!v.idea.id}">Post</button>-->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>                        
            <div class="modal-footer" style="display:none">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->    


<!-- Bootstrap modal used for people to create ideas -->
<div class="modal fade" id="newidea" data-easein="fadeInLeft" data-easeout="fadeOutLeft" >
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Share an Idea</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="group">      
                    <ui:inputText aura:id="createtitle" value="{!v.newIdea.Title}" required="true"/>
                    <span class="highlight"></span>
                    <span class="bar"></span>
                    <label class="material">Title</label>
                </div>

                <p>

                    <ui:inputText aura:id="createdescription" label="" placeholder="Details" value="{!v.newIdea.Body}" class="hidden" />

                    <textarea rows="4" cols="50" onchange="{!c.changeField}" placeholder="Tell us about it..."></textarea>

                </p>
                <div class="row">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="my-checkbox" class="toggle" value="{!v.newIdea.Merchants__Anonymous__c}" data-label-text="Anonymous" data-on-color="danger"/>                
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="my-checkbox" class="toggle" value="{!v.newIdea.Merchants__Confidential__c}" data-label-text="Confidential" data-on-color="danger"/>
                </div> 

                <select id="Category" value="{!v.newIdea.Category}">
                    <option value="Cost">Cost</option>
                    <option value="Revenue">Revenue</option>
                    <option value="Policy">Policy</option>
                </select>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">

                <a id="postButton" href="#" onclick="{!c.postIdea}" class="linkstandard red">Post</a>
                <a id="cancelButton" data-dismiss="modal" class="linkstandard grey">Cancel</a>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->        


<!-- Button to create an idea, the position is done via JS.  Not ideal, but it will check to see where
  it is continously, as I could not get a clean way to get an onscroll JS event for the UI
                 when using in S1 -->
<div class="row">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary circle" id="createidea" data-toggle="modal"
            data-target="#newidea">+</button>        
</div>
```

The Controller just for this:

```
openIdeaDetail : function(component, event, helper) {     
    var idea = component.get("v.idea");
    var selectedItem = event.currentTarget;
    var selectedId = selectedItem.dataset.ideaid;
    var evt = $A.get("e.merchants:OpenIdea");

    evt.setParams({"currentIdeaId": selectedId}).fire();    

  helper.getIdea(component, selectedId);    

  $j("#ideadetail").modal('show');}
```

And the Helper just for this:

```
getIdea: function(component, objectid, callback) {        
    var action = component.get("c.getIdea");
    action.setParams({
      "objectId": objectid
    });
    var self = this;

    action.setCallback(this, function(a) {
        component.set("v.idea", a.getReturnValue());
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);

    var action = component.get("c.getComments");
    action.setParams({
      "objectId": objectid
    });

    action.setCallback(this, function(a) {
        component.set("v.ideaComments", a.getReturnValue());

        // Hack - should use an aura:asyncRerender event, but the following
        // is done so this executes after the aura:iteration finishes
        // modifying the DOM after it gets data
        setTimeout(function(){
            $j(".timeago").timeago();
        }, 10);

    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);        
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

figured it out. The namespace is case sensitive so it should have been:

```
openIdeaDetail : function(component, event, helper) {     
var idea = component.get("v.idea");
var selectedItem = event.currentTarget;
var selectedId = selectedItem.dataset.ideaid;
**var evt = $A.get("e.Merchants:OpenIdea");**

evt.setParams({"currentIdeaId": selectedId}).fire();
```

`helper.getIdea(component, selectedId);`

`$j("#ideadetail").modal('show');}`